# update with self join results in NULLs

Tags: sqlite

I am moving from Access to SQLite. I am trying to recreate this update query:

#### Access

```
UPDATE FF_WBS_CONSOL
INNER JOIN FF_WBS_CONSOL AS [FF_WBS_CONSOL_1]
        ON FF_WBS_CONSOL.ParentWBS = [FF_WBS_CONSOL_1].WBS
SET FF_WBS_CONSOL.WBSLevel = [FF_WBS_CONSOL_1].[WBSLevel]+1
```

#### SQLite

```
UPDATE [FF_WBS_CONSOL]
SET [WBSLevel] = (SELECT P.[WBSLevel]+1
                  FROM [FF_WBS_CONSOL] P
                  WHERE [FF_WBS_CONSOL].[ParentWBS] = P.[WBS])
```

Results are all NULLs.

Answer (score 2):

In the Access query, the inner join runs only on those rows where a match was found.

In the SQLite query, the subquery is run on all rows; when no match was found, the subquery returns NULL. If the uppermost parent comes first in the table, its level is replaced by NULL, which is then propagated to the other rows.

You have to ensure that you update only those rows for which the subquery will find a match.
In most cases, you'd use `WHERE EXISTS (...same subquery...)`, but in this case, you can use a simpler filter:

```
UPDATE FF_WBS_CONSOL
SET WBSLevel = (SELECT P.[WBSLevel] + 1
                FROM FF_WBS_CONSOL AS P
                WHERE FF_WBS_CONSOL.ParentWBS = P.WBS)
WHERE ParentWBS IN (SELECT WBS FROM FF_WBS_CONSOL);
```

Comment: Thank you CL.

Yes indeed the uppermost parent is first in the table.
We were able to get this to work eventually with the WHERE EXISTS (...same query) but changed to your suggestion.

You may see more request for advice from us as we have a rather large Application whose current back end is Access that we are moving to SQLite. The application is required to have an Embedded Database.